# Clebsch--Gordan decomposition for $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, in indices

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $\pi_m$, $m \geq 0$, be the unitary irreps of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. The Clebsch--Gordan decomposition then gives that
$$ \pi_m \otimes \pi_n = \bigoplus_{k=0}^{\min(m,n)}\pi_{m+n-2k}.$$
But suppose I want to think of this decomposition as matrices. Evaluating at a point $x \in \mathrm{SU}(2)$, on the left I have
$$ (\pi_m(x))_{ij} (\pi_n(x))_{pq}.$$
How do the indices $i,j$ and $p,q$ correspond to the indices on the big matrix on the right?

**Some motivation for the question.** Expressions involving products of Fourier coefficients arise naturally in nonlinear harmonic analysis on $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. In this specific instance I am interested in calculating $\operatorname{Tr}(\hat{f}(\pi_m) \pi_m(x)) \operatorname{Tr}(\hat{f}(\pi_n)\pi_n(x)) = \hat{f}(\pi_m)^{ji} \hat{f}(\pi_n)^{qp} \pi_m(x)_{ij} \pi_n(x)_{pq}$ using the Clebsch--Gordan expansion above. Here $\hat{f}(\pi) = \int_{\mathrm{SU}(2)} f(x) \pi(x^{-1}) \mathrm{d} x. $

Comment: The only possible answer is "it depends".  The statement is that there is an isomorphism $\pi_m \otimes \pi_n \cong \bigoplus_{k = 0}^{\min(m, n)} \pi_{m + n - 2k}$; once you choose bases of the left- and right-hand sides, you'll get a matrix $A$ describing this isomorphism, and then the answer is that $A(\pi_m(x))_{i j}(\pi_n(x))_{p q}A^{-1}$ is the matrix of the direct-sum representation in terms of your chosen basis for the right-hand side.  Do you have a preferred choice of bases?

Comment: For the record, crossposted at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308012/clebsch-gordan-decomposition-for-mathrmsu2-in-indices/308015#308015.

Comment: @LSpice I suppose I would like the bases to be in some sense equivalent. For example, if $\pi_m$ acts on homogeneous degree $m$ polynomials in two complex variables, the vector space of such polynomials $\mathcal{P}_m$ has a standard basis $f_j$, $0 \leq j \leq m$. Is there a unique of extending this basis to the direct sum on the right-hand side?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'extending'.  Do you mean:  take the Cartesian products of your distinguished bases on the left-hand side, and the union of your distinguished bases on the right-hand side?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that would be it. Ultimately, the reason for my question is because I want to know how to contract the indices $(\pi_m(x))_{ij} (\pi_n(x))_{pq}$ on the left with a tensor $f^{ijpq}$, so the answer will be basis independent. But I want to do it in terms of the sum on the right!

Comment: The problem comes from harmonic analysis on $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, and I am dealing with the product $\operatorname{Tr}(\hat{f}(\pi_m) \pi_m(x)) \operatorname{Tr}(\hat{f}(\pi_n) \pi_n(x))$ for some function $f$ on $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. There is more detail to the problem that leads me to want to use the Clebsch--Gordan decomposition as above as a means to compute $\hat{f}(\pi_m)^{ji} \pi_m(x)_{ij} \hat{f}(\pi_n)^{qp} \pi_n(x)_{pq}$, but it might entirely be that I am missing something obvious!

Comment: I guess you mean by $\hat f(\pi)$ the operator $\int_{\operatorname{SU}(2)} f(g)\pi(g)\mathrm dg$, right?  Isn't $\operatorname{Tr}(\hat f(\pi_m)\pi_m(x))$ then just $(f * \operatorname{Tr}(\pi_m))(x)$, or something like that (maybe I flipped a sign somewhere)?

Comment: In my convention $\hat{f}(\pi)$ is $\int f(g) \pi(g^{-1}) \, \mathrm{d} g$, but yes, and I think I agree that $\operatorname{Tr}(\hat{f}(\pi_m) \pi_m(x)) = ( f * \operatorname{Tr}(\pi_m))(x)$. Does this help? (Ideally I want the end result in terms of $\hat{f}$, not $f$, but if this lends itself nicely to the decomposition then that would be useful too).

Comment: Hmm, maybe not.  I'll think more about it when time permits.  (I think that the motivation helps, though, and that you might do well to edit it into the problem.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has given me a few ideas to try too, and I will edit the question to include the motivation as well.